# Add class to closest span if textarea not empty (for many textareas and elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 365 textareas per page. I need an indicator in which textarea there is text. Add class "noted-dot" to the closest span if the textarea is not empty.

I was only able to do this for the first textarea (see second script). But I need to do this for every textarea that has text in it. Textarea gets text in two ways: from localStorage (see first script); after user input.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('localstoragesave');
var elementsParent = document.querySelector("textarea").closest("span");

// Not this script. It save textarea value in localStorage
function checkValidity() {};
for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
 (function(element) {
   var id = element.getAttribute('id');
   element.value = localStorage.getItem(id + location.search);
   element.oninput = function() {
     localStorage.setItem(id + location.search, element.value);
     checkValidity();
   };
 })(elements[i]);
}

// This script
window.onload = function() {
    if(elements[0].value > "") {
        document.querySelector("textarea").closest("span").classList.add("noted-dot");
    }
};
```

```html
<span class="badge rounded-pill dot dot-1">&ZeroWidthSpace;
    <div class="d-none date2022-10-28">
        <textarea class="localstoragesave form-control rounded-0 border-0 h-100" id="note-2022-10-28"></textarea>
    </div>
</span>
```

Comment: You mean if text is start to enter add the class in the closest span right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all textarea elements and add the class conditionally.

```
for (i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    if(elements[i].value != "") {
        elements[i].closest("span").classList.add("noted-dot");
    }
}
```

Fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/woce8pft/1/

Also if you want to add the doted-not class on input value change, add the conditions there too.